# How to get a list of predicates in Cayley graph

Tags: cayley

I have been playing around with the functionalities of open source Knowledge Graph implementation - Cayley https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/blob/master/docs/Quickstart-As-Application.md

It is interesting to know the queries are formulated naturally such as

```html
 // Let's get the list of actors in the film
 g.V().Has("<name>","Casablanca")
  .Out("</film/film/starring>").Out("</film/performance/actor>")
  .Out("<name>").All()
```

I would like to understand how can I get the list of all "predicates" that is valid for a node? One way I can think about is to manually go through the data dump (triplets). Is there any programatic way? or any schema querying tool available for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that the answer is straight forward but linked deep under the documentation of Gremlin API docs.

The Gremlin API provides, 
path.OutPredicates()
path.InPredicates()

https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/blob/master/docs/GremlinAPI.md#pathoutpredicates